# Installing Bootstrap 3 on Rails App

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm trying to install Bootstrap 3.0 on my Rails app. I recently finished Michael Hartl's tutorial and am now trying to build my own system using this new version of Bootstrap, but I have a few questions that I'm not sure about.

My system specs:

- OS X Mountain Lion on MBP
- Rails 4.0
- Ruby 2.0

Questions I have:

1. What is the best gem to use in my Gemfile? I have found a few of them.
2. What do I import on my `custom.css.scss`? I read somewhere that it's different from 2.3.2.
3. Is there anything else I have to do to get Bootstrap to work, or are the remaining steps identical to the ones I followed for Bootstrap 2.3.2?

**Edit**

Here is what the [bootstrap-rails project on GitHub](https://github.com/anjlab/bootstrap-rails) first says to do:

```
gem 'anjlab-bootstrap-rails', :require => 'bootstrap-rails',
                              :github => 'anjlab/bootstrap-rails'
```

Then it says to do:

```
gem 'anjlab-bootstrap-rails', '>= 3.0.0.0', :require => 'bootstrap-rails'
```

Do they do the same thing, or do you have to do them both?

Answer (score 272, accepted):

Actually you don't need gem for this, here is the step to install Bootstrap 3 in RoR

- [Download](http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/) Bootstrap
- **Copy:**

  `bootstrap-dist/css/bootstrap.css` and `bootstrap-dist/css/bootstrap.min.css`

  To: `vendor/assets/stylesheets`
- **Copy:**

  `bootstrap-dist/js/bootstrap.js` and `bootstrap-dist/js/bootstrap.min.js`

  To: `vendor/assets/javascripts`
- **Update:** `app/assets/stylesheets/application.css` by adding:

  ```
  *= require bootstrap.min
  ```
- **Update:** `app/assets/javascripts/application.js`by adding:

  ```
  //= require bootstrap.min
  ```

With this you can update bootstrap any time you want, don't need to wait gem to be updated. Also with this approach assets pipeline will use minified versions in production.

Comment: I agree. I also found that directly inserting the files runs into less issues in precompiling assets (e.g., for pushing to Heroku).

Comment: I get this error after following this procedure: 

    ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/assets/fontawesome-webfont.svg"):
   actionpack (3.2.14)      lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:21:in `call'

Comment: Is there any advantage to including the minified files in `vendor/assets/{stylesheets|javascripts}`? Sprockets should minify the files that are included in `app/assets/{stylesheets|javascripts}`.

Comment: How to include image and fonts files?

Comment: @wwli - See my answer below. It explains how to add the Glyphicons and fonts.

Comment: @don giulio No in rails it will automatically minifi so you only need the bootstrap.css and bootstrap.js in your app/assets folder and you shouldn't need to require anything rails will autoload any new style sheets or js files in that those folders automatically!

Comment: It didn't work for me, it seems that CSS and Javascript aren't served by my web server. I post a question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22947476/boostrap-in-a-rails-application-404-not-found . I use rails 3.2.17, but I don't think that this affects such a 'base' behaviors like the location of vendor CSS and JS

Comment: keep in mind his link to bootstrap is versioned so it is better to go get your own files off the site.  its easy

Comment: You haven't mentioned the order of the appended lines, Has to be something like this:                                                         *= require bootstrap.min
 *= require_self
 *= require_tree .
 */

Comment: why are you copying both bootstrap and bootstrap.min?

Comment: For noobs like me: you need to add '*= require bootstrap.min' in 'app/assets/stylesheets/application.css' before '*/', not after. Otherwise bootstrap css won't apply. Took some time to figure this out.

Comment: Can anybody explain the point of even using the asset pipeline for this instead of just adding the links found [here](http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/#download) to the head in `application.html.erb`? I'd rather load my assets from a CDN than from my own server.

Answer (score 63):

As many know, there is no need for a gem.

Steps to take:

1. Download Bootstrap

   - Direct download link [Bootstrap 3.1.1](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/releases/download/v3.1.1/bootstrap-3.1.1-dist.zip)
   - Or got to http://getbootstrap.com/
2. Copy

   ```
   bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css
   bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css
   ```

   to: `app/assets/stylesheets`
3. Copy

   ```
   bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.js
   bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js
   ```

   to: `app/assets/javascripts`
4. Append to: `app/assets/stylesheets/application.css`

   > *= require bootstrap
5. Append to: `app/assets/javascripts/application.js`

   > //= require bootstrap

**That is all.** You are ready to add a new cool Bootstrap template.

---

Why `app/` instead of `vendor/`?

It is important to add the files to **app/assets**, so in the future you'll be able to overwrite Bootstrap styles.

If later you want to add a `custom.css.scss` file with custom styles. You'll have something similar to this in `application.css`:

```
 *= require bootstrap                                                            
 *= require custom
```

If you placed the bootstrap files in **app/assets**, everything works as expected. But, if you placed them in **vendor/assets**, the Bootstrap files will be loaded last. Like this:

```
<link href="/assets/custom.css?body=1" media="screen" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="/assets/bootstrap.css?body=1" media="screen" rel="stylesheet">
```

So, some of your customizations won't be used as the Bootstrap styles will override them.

**Reason behind this**

Rails will search for assets in many locations; to get a list of this locations you can do this:

```
$ rails console
> Rails.application.config.assets.paths
```

In the output you'll see that **app/assets** takes precedence, thus loading it first.

Comment: Doesn't the order of the require statements in the application.css file control the order in which files are loaded rather than the order of the directories in the path list?  The order of the paths typcially controls which version of a file gest loaded if it is found in multiple directories included in the path list.  If not, how does the order of the require statements come into play?

Comment: Please don't copy minified versions, otherwise you'll get double include later (seems like 'require_tree .' works that way?). I was unable to open any dropdowns after installed [bootsy](https://github.com/volmer/bootsy) gem just because of this double-include.

Comment: @Kourindou Hime's comment seems to worth attention. I couldn't open dropdowns until I removed .min files.

Answer (score 35):

This answer is for those of you looking to Install Bootstrap 3 in your Rails app without using a gem. There are two simple ways to do this that take less than 10 minutes. Pick the one that suites your needs best. Glyphicons and Javascript work and I've tested them with the latest beta of Rails 4.1.0 as well.

1. [Using Bootstrap 3 with Rails 4](http://rvg.me/2013/11/using-bootstrap-3-with-rails-4/) - The Bootstrap 3 files are copied into the vendor directory of your application.
2. [Adding Bootstrap from a CDN to your Rails application](http://rvg.me/2014/01/adding-bootstrap-from-a-cdn-to-your-rails-application/) - The Bootstrap 3 files are served from the [Bootstrap CDN](http://www.bootstrapcdn.com).

Number 2 above is the most flexible. All you need to do is change the version number that is stored in a layout helper. So you can run the Bootstrap version of your choice, whether that is 3.0.0, 3.0.3 or even older Bootstrap 2 releases.

Comment: Can't seem to get this to work.  It keeps searching `localhost:3000/fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.svg` as an example in Chrome console, and the glyphicons aren't coming up (as a 404).

Comment: @Steve - I've assumed you are having the problem in development and that you chose #1 above. If that's accurate then, I'd double check that you copied Bootstrap fonts directory and all it's contents to `/vendor/assets/` in your project. You should also check your application.css to ensure you are requiring bootstrap.min and that you have the @font-face overrides. 

SCSS is widely used these days. If you are using that then you need change 'src: url' to 'src: asset-url' in the @font-face overrides.

There is also a sample project at the bottom of the post that may help.

Comment: I had no end of trouble with the fonts - worked fine in development but not in production. Ended up just putting them in public/fonts

Answer (score 22):

Twitter now has a [sass-ready version of bootstrap](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap-sass) with gem included, so it is easier than ever to add it to Rails.

Simply add to your gemfile the following:

```
gem 'sass-rails', '>= 3.2' # sass-rails needs to be higher than 3.2
gem 'bootstrap-sass', '~> 3.1.1'
```

`bundle install` and restart your server to make the files available through the pipeline.

There is also support for compass and sass-only: https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap-sass

Comment: Thanks.  A key point from the github readme for newbies; "If you have just generated a new Rails app, it may come with a .css file instead. If this file exists, it will be served instead of Sass, so rename it..."

Answer (score 11):

I use https://github.com/yabawock/bootstrap-sass-rails

Which is pretty much straight forward install, fast gem updates and followups and quick fixes in case is needed.

Comment: This gem is deprecated (as they point out themselves). Use the official SASS port instead: https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap-sass
(Also see this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/20875719/3451975)

Answer (score 5):

`gem bootstrap-sass`

bootstrap-sass is easy to drop into Rails with the asset pipeline.

In your Gemfile you need to add the bootstrap-sass gem, and ensure that the sass-rails gem is present - it is added to new Rails applications by default.

`gem 'sass-rails', '>= 3.2' # sass-rails needs to be higher than 3.2`
`gem 'bootstrap-sass', '~> 3.0.3.0'`

`bundle install` and restart your server to make the files available through the pipeline.

Source: http://rubydoc.info/gems/bootstrap-sass/3.0.3.0/frames

Answer (score 3):

Using this branch will hopefully solve the problem:

```
gem 'twitter-bootstrap-rails',
  git: 'git://github.com/seyhunak/twitter-bootstrap-rails.git',
  branch: 'bootstrap3'
```

Answer (score 3):

For me, the simplest way to do this is

1) Download and unzip bootstrap into `vendor`

2) Add the bootstrap path to your config

`config.assets.paths << Rails.root.join("vendor/bootstrap-3.3.6-dist")`

3) Require them

in css `*= require css/bootstrap`

in js `//= require js/bootstrap`

Done!

This methods makes the fonts load without any other special configuration and doesn't require moving the bootstrap files out of their self-contained directory.

Answer (score 1):

I think the most up to date gem for the new bootstrap version is form [anjlab](https://github.com/anjlab/bootstrap-rails).

But I don't know if it currently works good with other gems like simple_form when you do `rails generate simple_form:install --bootstrap`, etc. you may have to edit some initializers or configurations to fit the new bootstrap version.

Comment: Thanks for the response. So 'gem anjlab' in my Gemfile is all I have to do @tbraun89?

Comment: The readme is on the github page. The current gem is `gem "anjlab-bootstrap-rails", "~> 3.0.0.1"`.

Comment: In the readme they do this: `gem 'anjlab-bootstrap-rails', '>= 3.0.0.0', :require => 'bootstrap-rails'`

Comment: Thanks! I added something in the question. Could you clarify the part after 'edit'?

Comment: The first loads the files directly from github so when you do an bundle update you will have the newest version, the secound loads the gem from rubygems which is version 3.0.0.1 at the moment. (2 days old)

Answer (score 0):

I actually had an easy workaround on this one in which I nearly scratch my head on how to make it work. hahah!

Well, first I downloaded Bootstrap (the compiled css and js version).

Then I pasted all the bootstrap css files to the `app/assets/stylesheets/`.

And then I pasted all the bootstrap js files to the `app/assets/javascripts/`.

I reloaded the page and wallah! I just added bootstrap in my RoR!