# Textfield height issue after installing bootstrap 3 on rails

Tags: html, css, ruby-on-rails, ruby, twitter-bootstrap

After installing Bootstrap 3 to my rails app, the height of the text fields shrunk and some positioning went nuts. I haven't made any changes to my bootstrap files, other than manually adding the files to my vendors/stylesheets folder. I also looked at the doctype as I've seen others mentioning that could be the problem, but everything seems right with it. Does anyone has experienced this issue after adding bootstrap 3?

To install bootstrap 3 I followed this thread: [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18371318/installing-bootstrap-3-on-rails-app)

My application.html.erb had the `<!DOCTYPE html>`

Here is how my app looks with Bootstrap 3:
[image: Bootstrap 3]

And here is how it should look (with the previous version of bootstrap):
[image: Bootstrap]

Note that I can trigger this by adding\removing `*= require bootstrap`
 from my application.css.scss file.

Can anyone help me?

Comment: Luiz, is the style coming from bootstrap? That seems to be the logical source. Why can't you just override it in your stylesheet?

Comment: Also, we need examples.

Comment: Yes, the style is coming from the bootstrap. It's hard to give you examples as I don't know from where the problem is coming from since I haven't override anything besides adding the bootstrap 3 files into the vendors folder. I had previous bootstrap version working perfectly and I followed the steps from the link above and what triggered the bootstrap 3 to work was adding `*= require bootstrap` to my application.css.scss file. After that some formfields and positioning go nuts.

Comment: @screenmutt Not sure if images help, but I've edited my question and added some images. Let me know if this helps somehow.. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

When you migrate from Bootstrap 2 to 3, be sure to check all your formatting attributes.  For text field height, `<input type='text'>` used to work, but now you need `<input type='text' class='form-control'>`.

For other readers of this answer, whenever you install Bootstrap, make sure that you add the appropriate class attributes to the HTML tags in your views.  Otherwise, it may look like things have shrunk.  For example,

```
Welcome, visitor!  What is your name?
<%= text_field_tag 'name' >
```

should become

```
Welcome, visitor!  What is your name?
<%= text_field_tag 'name', nil, class: 'form-control' >
```

Note that in Rails, you can specify the class of form elements using the form helpers by passing `class: 'your-class-here'`

Bootstrap works by setting class attributes everywhere.  See the following documentation:

http://getbootstrap.com/css (Bootstrap documentation)

http://getbootstrap.com/css/#forms-control-sizes (resizing text fields)

Comment: Does this answer your question, Luiz?  If so please, accept it.  Thanks!

Comment: Thanks @earksiinni! But it didn't solve the problem as I'm doing exactly as you mentioned, every style under the class work just fine, it's just the height of form fields that has shrunk for some unknown reason. Please see the images above. Thanks again