# Importing a Start Bootstrap Theme

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, themes

I want to import a Start Bootstrap theme on my Rails project that I just created. It's a full-site theme, so it comes with the HTML pages as well as the assets (fonts, CSS, JS files).

I'm guessing the assets go into the asset pipeline (assets/*) but what do I do with the bootstrap.css files that come with the theme? Since I have the bootstrap gem installed, I figure it would be redundant for me to put bootstrap files into the asset pipeline.

Also, where would the HTML pages go?

Thanks so much!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**HTML**

If you have already generated the html files by Rails, you can copy the content of downloaded file and paste it to the existed file (e.g. index.html.erb).

**ASSETS**

You can copy:

- javascripts to app/assets/javascripts
- css to app/assets/stylesheets
- fonts to app/assets/stylesheets/fonts
- images to public assets/images

If you are using fonts and you placed them in app/assets/stylesheets/fonts, it could be needed to change a content of css files. It is possible that paths to fonts can be like:
 '/../fonts/glyphicons-halflings.eot'
and you should to change it to:
 'fonts/glyphicons-halflings.eot'

Answer (score 1):

If you are using sprockets on your rails app (https://github.com/rails/sprockets-rails), you can import this files at the top of your assets.

Check also [Installing Bootstrap 3 on Rails App](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18371318/installing-bootstrap-3-on-rails-app)