# boostrap in a rails application, 404 (Not Found)

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails-3, twitter-bootstrap

I've tried to integrate bootstrap following [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18371318/installing-bootstrap-3-on-rails-app) procedure found on stackoverflow (my rails version is the 3.2.17, this is a difference), so without a gem but just including the bootstrap files in the relevant project directories. 
Then i've created an HTML page and i put it in the project public directory. 
This is the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Bootsrap Test 01</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.css">
    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>

...
```

But when i load the page and inspect it (it loads) i can see that the GETs produces the errors below:

```
GET http://localhost:3000/css/bootstrap.css 404 (Not Found) 
GET http://localhost:3000/js/bootstrap.min.js 404 (Not Found)
```

Comment: did you restart your server?

Comment: yes, i restarted the server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The path is not:

```
css/bootstrap.css
```

but

```
assets/bootstrap.css
```

Answer (score 2):

From the error i think your app try to find **bootstrap.css** in a folder called **css** inside your **public directory** and another file called **bootstrap.min.js** in a folder called **js** inside the **public directory** too, so verify if this is what you are doing :)

this is my preferred way for adding bootstrap to Rails app :

1. copy bootstrap.min.css to /vendor/assets/stylesheets
2. copy bootstrap.min.js to /vendor/assets/javascripts
3. copy fonts directory to /vendor/assets/

then add this line : `*= require bootstrap.min` to *app/assets/stylesheets/application.css* file like this :

```
 *= require bootstrap.min
 *= require_self
 *= require_tree .
```

and also add `//= require bootstrap.min` to *app/assets/javascripts/application.js* file like this :

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require bootstrap.min
//= require_tree .
```

**Restart** your server and that's it.

Hope this help