# rails and bootstrap: Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap

I created a simple webapp integrating bootstrap 3 in a rails 3.2.17 application, following [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18371318/installing-bootstrap-3-on-rails-app) procedure found on stackoverflow, so without using a gem but manually copying the bootstrap files in the relevant app directories.

Even if i have, in my gem file:

```
gem 'jquery-rails'
```

i can still see, inspecting my web page with chrome, the error:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined
```

My page is a "normal" html page in public directory. Maybe it doesn't "inherit" all the assets stuff? The code is like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Bootsrap Test 01</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/bootstrap.css">
    <script src="/js/bootstrap.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>

...
```

I've not yet tried but i guess that javascript based feature won't work.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Assuming that after adding `gem 'jquery-rails'`, you have ran `bundle install` command.

Make sure you have following in `app/assets/javascripts/application.js`

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require bootstrap.min   // Add it after jquery and jquery_ujs
```

**EDIT**

You will need to explicitly include jQuery before including `/bootstrap.min.js`. For example :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Bootsrap Test 01</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/bootstrap.css">
    <script src="/assets/jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="/assets/jquery_ujs.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="/js/bootstrap.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>
```

Comment: bundle install gave me (among others) this output: Using jquery-rails (3.1.0).
Regarding the other point, in my app/assets/javascripts/application.js there are two entries //= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs. The problem is that i think that they don't affect a "custom" page that I create in public folder. Wait. this needed to be said. I update the question.

Comment: Ok, it worked exactly as you said. 1) please consider that i updated the href and src to start with a / because otherwise it works just inside the root folder. So if you want, you can make the same update in your answer. 2) maybe it is worth to mention that jquery and jquery_ujs have to come *before* bootstrap. Newbies remark.

Comment: @AgostinoX Added it to the answer. :)

Answer (score 16):

Even if you have set jquery correctly you can still see that issue when you inline javascript code is evoked before jQuery is initialized.

You can wrap your javascript code in

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) { 
  //do work with $
});
```

Or refactor your code to not use inline javascript :)

Answer (score 12):

on 'application.js' of rails 5.0.1 the default is

```
//= require bootstrap
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require turbolinks
//= require_tree .
```

change it to

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require turbolinks
//= require_tree .
//= require bootstrap
```

*load first jquery before bootstrap

Comment: This is the answer , perfect !

Comment: Had a similar problem, and the solution was change the ordering as well :+1:

Answer (score 1):

Another place to check is the `<head>` of the `application.html.erb` file.

Be sure that you're loading in jQuery before the Bootstrap javascript.

Comment: How do you correctly load it though? I am about to go crazy. Aren't we supposed to use `<% javascript_include_tag %>`  or something? I would really appreciate your answer. I've been trying this for hours...

Answer (score 0):

I came across the same error message in the console.

Just make sure jQuery is above Bootstrap in your 'assets/javascripts/application.js' file

Solution:

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require jquery-ui
//= require bootstrap
```