# jQuery DOM event listener failed with "$ is not defined"

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails

Following the advice [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26821499/1299362), I have the following inline code in a Ruby on Rails app:

```
  document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) { 
    $("select#graph_line_duration").change(function(){
        $("form").submit();
    });
    $("input#graph_duration").hide();
  });
```

I am getting an error `$ is not defined`.  However, if I click on a link to go to the page, then the code works fine, so my `jquery` assets are loading, given sufficient time.

Comment: Is jQuery imported before/above this inline script? That is the cause if it's not.

Comment: How are you loading jQuery, and is it loaded earlier in the HTML than your script?

Comment: I am using the ruby on rails asset pipeline and sprockets to load jQuery. It loading should be initiated before the html.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
document.addEventListener("load", function(event) { ... })
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/DOMContentLoaded

> The DOMContentLoaded event is fired when the document has been completely loaded and parsed, without waiting for stylesheets, images, and subframes to finish loading (the load event can be used to detect a fully-loaded page).

Comment: This listener did not fire at all, so my jquery code was not executed.

Comment: you can try in that case `window.addEventListener` as per this link https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/load 
Try putting console.log() in document.addEventListener as first statement to see if it fires.

Answer (score 0):

Look the order of your imports, i.e.:

```
//= require_self
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
```

Comment: I have altered the order to be as you have indicated, but that still does not help.  Why is the event listener for DOMContentLoaded firing, even if jQuery is not loaded yet?

Answer (score 0):

You may not have jQuery loaded when you run it, due to network latency.

Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) { 
        $("select#graph_line_duration").change(function(){
            $("form").submit();
        });
        $("input#graph_duration").hide();
    });
});
```

This runs the javascript after jQuery has fully loaded, but has to appear in the HTML file after the `<script>` tag that loads jQuery.

Comment: the `$` on `$(document)` will still be undefined :D