# Loading Bootstrap Glyphicons with Rails 3.2

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, asset-pipeline, glyphicons

I'm trying to use Bootstrap Glyphicons in my Rails app.  I tried following the instructions on the following page:

https://gist.github.com/iamatypeofwalrus/6467148

But when I run my app, the icons do not appear and I get the following error in my console:

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) http://0.0.0.0:3000/fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) http://0.0.0.0:3000/fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.ttf
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) http://0.0.0.0:3000/assets/fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) http://0.0.0.0:3000/assets/fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.ttf
```

Any ideas what might be wrong?

My glyphicon files are all in vendor > assets > fonts

My bootstrap-glyphicons.css file was edited to have the following line:

```
@font-face{font-family:'Glyphicons Halflings';src:url('/assets/glyphicons-halflings-regular.eot');src:url('/assets/glyphicons-halflings-regular.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),url('/assets/glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff') format('woff'),url('/assets/glyphicons-halflings-regular.ttf') format('truetype'),url('/assets/glyphicons-halflings-regular.svg#glyphicons-halflingsregular') format('svg');}.glyphicon{position:relative;top:1px;display:inline-block;font-family:'Glyphicons Halflings';font-style:normal;font-weight:normal;line-height:1;-webkit-font-smoothing:antialiased;}
```

Comment: How do you have Bootstrap installed on your Rails application? If Rails version is 4.0 or later, you should use the `bootstrap-sass` gem as well as their documentation.

Comment: I'm using Rails 3.2.  I installed Bootstrap manually without a gem following these instructions: http://stackoverflow.com/a/18371521/1720985

Answer (score 0):

I believe you have not completed step 4 in that Gist correctly. You need to update Font URL in your CSS file so that it references correct location.

Example:

```
src:url('../fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.eot');
```

becomes

```
src:url('/assets/glyphicons-halflings-regular.eot');
```

According to your error message, I can see that it still references to wrong location, which is `/assets/fonts` (The correct path should not have `fonts` in URL)

Regards,

Comment: thanks for your help.  I believe that I've followed the step correctly (I updated my post above to reflect what I have in the css file)

Comment: Then, I believe that there should be another font-face definition somewhere in your CSS which make browser request a different file from your specified location. You should double check