# routing error to save avatar paperclip

Tags: ruby-on-rails

ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/system/images/avatars/000/000/003/small/rails.jpg%3F1416564723")

Comment: what do controllers have to do with bootstrap? It's a front-end framework.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Installing Bootstrap 3 on Rails App](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18371318/installing-bootstrap-3-on-rails-app)

Comment: https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap-sass

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add it in Gemfile:

```
gem 'bootstrap-sass', '~> 3.2.0'
gem 'sass-rails', '4.0.3'
```

And execute:

```
bundle install
```

If you want use it - create custom file(.css.scss) in assets/stylesheets and write css using sass syntax.