# Bootstrap 3.0 on my Rails app is not working

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, heroku

I have follow the steps which are given here :

[Installing Bootstrap 3 on Rails App](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18371318/installing-bootstrap-3-on-rails-app)

I have copied files from bootstrap folder to my application folder.

Its working fine on my localhost:3000 but when I deploy it to heroku server and open it to my mobile its not displying as mobile responsive.
URL to my demo app:
appu.herokuapp.com

please reply

Comment: Did you include bootstrap .css and .js into your application ?

Comment: yes I have included that files to my application.css and application.js

Answer (score 0):

You have to precompile your assets for them to be used by Heroku.  Run this in your terminal:

> ```
> RAILS_ENV=production rake assets:precompile
> ```

More on this: [Heroku Assets](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/rails-asset-pipeline)
 
Then manage as always with git and upload to heroku

> git add -A

```
git commit -m "message"

git push heroku master
```

Comment: the logs from Heroku                                                                       **'Preparing app for Rails asset pipeline'**
       'Running: rake assets:precompile'
       'Asset precompilation completed (11.17s)'
       'Cleaning assets'
       'Running: rake assets:clean'   should we run RAILS_ENV=production rake assets:precompile

Comment: If I am not mistaken (I haven't used heroku for a month now), you should precompile the assets in your env before uploading them for this to work.