# Glyphicons not showing them all and the ones shown have a tiny size

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap-3, glyphicons

I followed [these steps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18371318/installing-bootstrap-3-on-rails-app) (accepted answer) to use Bootstrap 3 in RoR (specifically I'm using Bootstrap 3.3.6 in my RoR app), it works perfect in every way, except for glyphicons, the problem I have with the glyphicons is that I can visualize much as 50% of them, and even though the ones that are shown have an extremely small size.

How can I solve this problem?

**Code in html.erb**

```
  </div>
</nav>

<i class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></i>
<i class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></i>

<div class="container">
  <h1>Instituciones</h1>
```

**View:**

[image]

Comment: There's a number of problems with this question. You haven't provided any contextual code and your screenshot and problem description conflict ("[...] glyphicon glyphicon-plus doesn't show anything" but it's clearly there in the screenshot).

Comment: @AndréDion Oh yeah, sorry, glyphicon glyphicon-plus works fine, I got confused with another one

Answer (score 2):

### Nifty glypihicon scaling

Glyphicon size is inherited from the text it `spans`. A way to easily work with glyphicons is to define a set of scalers in your .css

```
/* Glypicons sizing */
.gi-1-5x{font-size: 1.5em;}
.gi-2x{font-size: 2em;}
.gi-3x{font-size: 3em;}
.gi-4x{font-size: 4em;}
.gi-5x{font-size: 5em;}
.gi-7x{font-size: 7em;}
.gi-10x{font-size: 10em;}
```

etc...

**Usage**

```
<span class="glyphicon-plus gi-2x" aria-hidden="true"></span>
<span class="glyphicon-pencil gi-10x" aria-hidden="true"></span>
```

Answer (score 0):

In your print screen I can see both icons (plus, pencil), they are just too small... glyphicon is a font, so you can just increase the size with css:

```
.glyphicon {
  font-size: XXXXpx;
}
```