# Why isn't Rails acknowledging relative JavaScript files?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails

app/assets/javascripts/application.js:

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require_tree .
//= require bootstrap.min
```

app/assets/javascripts/economy.js:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  console.log("loaded file");
});
```

app/views/economy/index.html.erb:

```
<%= javascript_include_tag "economy" %>
```

app/config/initializers/assets.rb:

```
Rails.application.config.assets.version = '1.0'
Rails.application.config.assets.precompile += %w( economy.js )
```

Why doesn't economy.js print anything to the console when a page in my app is loaded?

I tried adding `//= require economy.js` but that didn't change anything, and should be redundant if I understand how `require_tree` works.

Answer (score 0):

You're right that it should be automatically included.

The only thing that jumps out, given this level of detail, is that you have `//= require bootstrap.min` in there and a `require` should never have a file extension. It may be breaking all the requires. Change that to `//= require bootstrap` or for the sake of testing economy.js loading or remove it entirely for now.

If that doesn't work, here's a few things to try:

1. Try an `alert("loaded file");` in case there is an issue with you browser console.
2. Try adding `//= require economy` without the `.js`.
3. Check the browser's sources to see if the file got loaded to narrow down the issue.

Also, don't forget to close your `$(document).ready` call with a `;` at the end of `})`.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I tried it all, though, and nothing changed. I was instructed to use `//= require bootstrap.min` [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18371318/installing-bootstrap-3-on-rails-app). I'll post a few more of my files to see if they provide any further hints. Is there anything specific you'd like to see?

Comment: Are there an errors in your `rails server` output when you load the page? I'm guessing there're no errors in your browsers console and that the .js is definitely not being loaded in the sources, correct?

Comment: I'm actually getting this error: 
ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/assets/bootstrap.min.css.map")... I have no idea what it means but I think it's unrelated.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer. My app/assets/javascripts folder had a file called economy.coffee (for some reason?!), and all I had to do was remove it. I think it was overwriting my js file or something.