# Unable to load Bootstrap.min file

Tags: ruby-on-rails, bootstrapping

I am trying to load bootstrap in my rails application. But it is not working. I had included the `bootstrap` and `sass` gems in my `Gemfile`. The following is my `application.js` file:

```
//= require bootstrap
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require turbolinks
//= require_tree .
```

I have also tried using `bootstrap-cdn` but it did not solve my problem. And I am unable to load bootstrap.min file in the application.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: maybe you looking for this solution: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18371318/installing-bootstrap-3-on-rails-app

Answer (score 0):

Add **`.min`** after bootstrap or rails will search for **`bootstrap.js`** instead of **`bootstrap.min.js`**

```
//= require bootstrap.min
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require turbolinks
//= require_tree .
```

**NOTE:** Same applies for **`bootstrap.min.css`**

Comment: Hello Deepak,I  added .min in my application.js and application.css..but its not working and if I add bootstrap.min in my css file,i am facing an error:   "couldn't find file 'bootstrap.min' with type 'text/css'"..but i actually have bootstrap.min file in my project.