# Weird issue with Bootstrap and Ruby on Rails

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap

I am completely stuck at the moment with a really weird problem:

[image: how the navbar component is shown]

I tried to add bootstrap to my RoR Project several times like described here:

- https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap-sass
- [Installing Bootstrap 3 on Rails App](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18371318/installing-bootstrap-3-on-rails-app)

Both approaches don't really work, which makes no sense to me, apparently the .css .js files are there because you can see that some styling is applied but not how it should be.
I also considered that my browser(chrome) messes things up but it looks the same with safari.
I also tried different versions of rails which also did not work.

**really weird**: I have also similar problems when choosing foundation instead of bootstrap

I would be incredibly thankful for anything that helps me with this issue!

layouts/application.html.erb:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Alphablog</title>
    <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
    <%= csp_meta_tag %>

    <%= stylesheet_link_tag    'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>
    <%= javascript_include_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>
  </head>

  <body>
    <%= yield %>
  </body>
</html>
```

application.js:

```
// This is a manifest file that'll be compiled into application.js, which will include all the files
// listed below.
//
// Any JavaScript/Coffee file within this directory, lib/assets/javascripts, or any plugin's
// vendor/assets/javascripts directory can be referenced here using a relative path.
//
// It's not advisable to add code directly here, but if you do, it'll appear at the bottom of the
// compiled file. JavaScript code in this file should be added after the last require_* statement.
//
// Read Sprockets README (https://github.com/rails/sprockets#sprockets-directives) for details
// about supported directives.
//
//= require jquery.min
//= require bootstrap.min
//= require rails-ujs
//= require activestorage
//= require turbolinks
//= require_tree .
```

application.scss:

```
/*
 * This is a manifest file that'll be compiled into application.css, which will include all the files
 * listed below.
 *
 * Any CSS and SCSS file within this directory, lib/assets/stylesheets, or any plugin's
 * vendor/assets/stylesheets directory can be referenced here using a relative path.
 *
 * You're free to add application-wide styles to this file and they'll appear at the bottom of the
 * compiled file so the styles you add here take precedence over styles defined in any other CSS/SCSS
 * files in this directory. Styles in this file should be added after the last require_* statement.
 * It is generally better to create a new file per style scope.
 *
 *= require bootstrap.min
 *= require_tree .
 *= require_self
 */
```

Comment: please add code from layouts/application.html.erb, application.js and application.css to the question

Comment: layouts/application.html.erb :
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Alphablog</title>
    <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
    <%= csp_meta_tag %>

    <%= stylesheet_link_tag    'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>
    <%= javascript_include_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>
  </head>

  <body>
    <%= yield %>
  </body>
</html>

Comment: application.js:

//= require jquery.min
//= require bootstrap.min
//= require rails-ujs
//= require activestorage
//= require turbolinks
//= require_tree .

Comment: application.css:

 *= require bootstrap.min
 *= require_tree .
 *= require_self

Comment: Add them to the question, not on the comments

Comment: Did you rename `application.css` to `application.scss`?